# SQLite Trigger Expression For Deleting Rows

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

I've 2 tables A(id, Name), B(id, fid, Name) where **A.id = B.fid**, My requirement is I want to delete Row in B whenever row in A deletes

Here is query which i tried but it gives me Error near B..

```
Create Trigger Delete_B_trigger After Delete on A For each row Begin Delete from B where fid = id; End
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The DELETE command [requires](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) a FROM.

To access values in the triggering table, you have to use the [OLD or NEW](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) aliases.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Delete_B_trigger
AFTER DELETE ON A
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM B WHERE fid = OLD.id;
END
```

Comment: Thanks... I didnt get the use and meaning of OLD and NEW aliases.can you give some link to refer about it

Comment: Other than the link to the official SQLite documentation, which is already there?

Comment: @Pradeep: NEW refers to an inserted or updated version of a row (or rows). OLD refers to the pre-existing version of the row.  In a delete operation, there is no NEW version of the row, only the OLD version of the row (or rows).

Comment: @Pradeep: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981353/how-to-enable-foreign-key-cascade-delete-by-default-in-sqlite